# Javascript Execution context memory management

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

I have been struggling to get an answer for my question but not good.

In javascript when the Interpreter initialize an execution context , is the size of it determined, if so what would happen if one of the data members (lets say array) exceeds this size, will this be considered an overflow? or will there be some memory allocation mechanism to solve this?

Comment: I think the only overflow in javascript is in Math. Any other types/classes acts as object and you can add/remove without error

Comment: What about stack overflow on recursive faults?